# Reduce space between names.arg and axis (box) in barplot

Tags: r, bar-chart, whitespace

I created a simple `barplot` surrounded by a box. Is there any way to move my names closer to the box (space marked in blue)?

MWE:

```
set.seed(1)
count <- runif(n = 3, min = 0, max = 10)
names <- letters[seq(from = 1, to = 3)]

barplot(height = count,
        names.arg = names,
        horiz = TRUE,
        las = 1)
box()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two ways to do this. You can use `rect` instead of `box` to move the box boundary to the left:

```
barplot(height=count, names.arg=names, horiz=TRUE, las=1)
bounds <- par("usr")
rect(bounds[1]-.1, bounds[3], bounds[2], bounds[4], xpd=NA)
```

[image: Change Box]

Or you can add the y-axis separately which lets you control where the labels are plotted:

```
x <- barplot(height=count, horiz=TRUE, las=1)
box()
axis(2, x, names, las=1, tick=FALSE, mgp=c(2, .35, 0))
```

[image: Set y-axis]

Adjust the middle value in `mgp` to position the labels (see `?par`)